# GeoJSON is a directory error on Linux

Tags: geojson, geopandas, linux

I need to inspect the source code of a GeoJSON file written with `geopandas` because QGIS has trouble correctly interpreting the CRS and I'd like to get to the root cause of it.

I tried with `nano` and `gedit` but in both cases I get the cryptic `[ "T52WES_6b20m_k5_xgb0_2v_se08.geojson" is a directory ]` error.

What's going on there? How can I see the text of the file?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/415558/edit) to include a code snippet showing exactly how you wrote the file with geopandas.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> GeoDataFrame.to_file(filename, driver=None, schema=None, index=None, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> Write the GeoDataFrame to a file.
>
> ***By default, an ESRI shapefile is written***, but any OGR data source
> supported by Fiona can be written.

If you want geojson, you need to specify the GeoJSON driver:

```
gdf.to_file('output.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

Comment: ya it's always great when the docs contradict themselves. A little further down it says "driver [...] If not specified, it attempts to infer it from the file extension." I was counting on that. And that having a full stop in the filename would make it look like a file, I didn't know this could happen. So that's where the confusion came from.

Comment: Turns out I'm using an older version of GeoPandas. The docs on my machine don't include the line about the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

What happened is that `geopandas` wrote a directory of shapefile called `T52WES_6b20m_k5_xgb0_2v_se08.geojson` which my file browser `thunar` interpreted as a file instead of a directory.

To save the file I used `geopandas.GeoSeries.to_file`.

> GeoSeries.to_file(filename, driver=None, index=None, **kwargs) Write
> the GeoSeries to a file.
>
> By default, an ESRI shapefile is written, but any OGR data source
> supported by Fiona can be written.
>
> Parameters filenamestring File path or file handle to write to.
>
> driver string, default None The OGR format driver used to write the
> vector file. If not specified, it attempts to infer it from the file
> extension. If no extension is specified, it saves ESRI Shapefile to a
> folder.
>
> [...]

When I removed the file extension, it suddenly appeared as a directory.